# Sometimes, UserDefaults reloads the deleted data after relaunching the app

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I found a weird behavior when using UserDefaults to save/load data, what I do as below.

1. Swipe to delete data/row in tableView.
2. Relaunch the app to load data from UserDefaults again.
3. I try this many times and using both simulator and iPhone, sometimes the removed row is showed again when app is re-launched.

Well, it is a random issue that I check my code but didn't found clues. My data model is very simple, so it should be saved and load quickly. Would you gives me some hint/advice?

### Model

```
class Note: Codable {
    var content: String
    
    init(content: String) {
        self.content = content
    }
}
```

### ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    ...
    var notes = [Note]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        loadData()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return notes.count
    }
    
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        
        let node = notes[indexPath.row].content
        cell.textLabel?.text = node
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = DetailViewController()
        vc.bodyText = notes[indexPath.row].content
        
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            notes.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            print("notes: \(notes)")
            saveData()
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            count = notes.count
        }
    }
    
    @objc func createNewNote() {
        let vc = NewNoteViewController()
        vc.notes = notes
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

            if let savedNotes = defaults.object(forKey: "notes") as? Data {
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                do {
                    self?.notes = try jsonDecoder.decode([Note].self, from: savedNotes)
                    print("Load notes: \(String(describing: self?.notes))")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.tableView.reloadData()
                        self?.count = self?.notes.count ?? 0
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Failed to load notes")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func saveData() {
        DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
            let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
            
            if let savedData = try? jsonEncoder.encode(self?.notes) {
                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                defaults.set(savedData, forKey: "notes")
                print("value saved")
            } else {
                print("Failed to save notes")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only reason I suspect is that you save data in async, so if you quit the app too soon it may not have enough time to finish saveData(). Does it happen if you wait a bit before re-lounching the app ?

Comment: Maybe unrelated but don’t `[weak self]` in `DispatchQueue` closures. They don’t cause retain cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserDefaults` doesn't write the data to disk immediately, it waits to perform batch writes for performance reasons.

If you're re-launching the app through Xcode it might be killing the app before it has the chance to persist the changes.

Try force closing the app on the device instead of re-launching with Xcode, or just wait a few more seconds before re-launching and this shouldn't happen.

To be clear, what you're seeing is not an issue, it's a side-effect of the way you're launching the app. Don't worry about it, it won't affect the way your app works once it's installed.

Comment: Yes! If I force the app and re-launch it without Xcode, this issue is gone. So you mean `UserDefaults` need time to save the data, even a very small data. I try to check the native `Notes` app in iPhone, which is very fast. So, run from Xcode may causes this issue, right?

Comment: It's not that it **needs** time to save the data. It waits on purpose because writing to disk takes time; if you were to make a ton of changes to `UserDefaults` in a short period of time it could slow down your app. When you force-close the app, `UserDefaults` reacts to that and writes its data to disk. If you re-launch with Xcode you kill the app without giving `UserDefaults` a chance to react. And to be clear, what you're seeing is not an issue, it's a side-effect of the way you're launching the app. Don't worry about it, it won't affect the way your app works once it's installed.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that [weak self] gets disposed before the async task has a chance to run.

1. Try to pass `self.notes` as a parameter to saveData(_ notes: [Note]) instead of accessing it via `self?.notes` inside the closure.
2. probably an overshoot here, but you may want to look at:
   [Extending Your App's Background Execution Time](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/extending_your_app_s_background_execution_time)

Comment: Thanks, normally I would use `weak` capture list in closure. I have used your approach but this issue is happened again. Thus, the reason could be as @EmilioPelaez said or you mentioned in comments, `UserDefault` needs time write the data.